# How to return packed array to localparam in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I have a Verilog localparam and a function declared as:

```
localparam [7:0] someParam[0:15] = someFunc(8'h10);

function [7:0][15:0] someFunc();
  input [7:0] some_input;

  someFunc[0]  = 8'h00;
  ...
  ...
endfunction
```

The error I get is: cannot assign packed to unpacked. Any solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Verilog doesn't support multi-dimensional parameter arrays as stated in:

- IEEE1364-1995 § 3.10 *Parameters*
- IEEE1364-2001 § 3.11.1 *Module parameters*
- IEEE1364-2005 § 4.10.1 *Module parameters*

There is a ways to do it with SystemVerilog. Multi-dimensional declarations are not supported, however a parameter type can be `typdef` which can be multi-dimensional. The same is true for the return type of a function. See [IEEE1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 6.20.1 *Parameter declaration syntax* and § 6.18 *User-defined types*.

Example:

```
typedef logic [7:0] someType [16];
localparam someType someParam = someFunc(8'h10);

function someType someFunc (input [7:0] some_input);
  someFunc[0]  = 8'h00;
  // ...
endfunction
```

Similarly, Verilog does not support double packed arrays (ex `[7:0][15:0] someFunc`).

- IEEE1364-1995 § 10.3.1 *Defining a function*
- IEEE1364-2001 § 10.3.1 *Function declarations*
- IEEE1364-2005 § 10.4.1 *Function declarations*

SystemVerilog does support double packed arrays. So another solution is:

```
localparam [15:0][7:0] someParam = someFunc(8'h10);

function [15:0][7:0] someFunc (input [7:0] some_input);
  someFunc[0]  = 8'h00;
  // ...
endfunction
```

*Note: you want `[15:0][7:0]` which is 16 arrays of 8-bits, not `[7:0][15:0]` which is 8 arrays of 16-bits.*